# Unable to locate function inside a model using Codeigniter 3 w/ HMVC

Tags: php, codeigniter

I can't access my function inside my model. Here's my code:

**Controller**
*service_category.php*

```
class Service_Category extends MX_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {

        $data = array();
        $data['system_title'] = 'Admin- Service Category';
        $data['header'] = modules::run('common/header/index', $data);
        $data['sidebar_left'] = modules::run('common/sidebar_left/index', $data);
        $data['sidebar_right'] = modules::run('common/sidebar_right/index', $data);
        $data['footer'] = modules::run('common/footer/index', $data);

        $breadcrumbs = array(
            'home' => site_url('users/user'),
            'service category' => site_url('reports/service_category'),
        );

        $data['breadcrumbs'] = gen_breadcrumbs($breadcrumbs);
        $this->load->model('reports/Service_category');
        $services = $this->Service_category->get_category(); //error here cant locate
        fp($services);

        $this->load->view('service_category', $data);

    }

}
```

**Model** *Service_category.php*

```
class Service_category extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function get_category() {

        $services = $this->db->get('tr_project_services');
        if($services) {
            return $services->result();
        } else {
            return array();
        }
    }

}
```

Here's my error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Service_Category::get_category() 

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Call to undefined method Service_Category::get_category()

Filename: controllers/service_category.php

Line Number: 25

Backtrace:
```

I put my model inside my modules.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the answer to my question. All I need to replace is my model name. I don't know if it is a new naming convention.

What I did is I replace my model name `Service_category` to `Service_model`

Comment: And your controller as well file name needs to be Service_category.php

Comment: Unless namespace is used, classes need to be named distinctively. Your model and controller was named the same.